# Spring Data JPA Select Distinct dynamic columns based on list of string input

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I want to select columns based on my input (List < String >)

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Product {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  
  private String name;
  private String price;
}
```

I understand that to select distinct specific columns, I can use @Query("SELECT DISTINCT name FROM TABLE")
However, I want to give users the flexibility to select the columns they want. e.g. List < String > columns = Arrays.asList(["name", "price"]). This will then select distinct from both name and price columns.

Answer (score 0):

For this create a [custom method implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) and use one of the following (or of the many variants thereof)

- construct a SQL or JPQL query using String concatenation (be careful not to introduce SQL injection vulnerabilities).
- use some kind of criteria API like

  - JPA Criteria API
  - Querydsl
  - JOOQ